# WordPress : printing custom fields content in pages

Tags: php, wordpress, custom-post-type

I'm working with custom post types. post type is created using types plugin. Custom post type name is `partners` that  has title , featured image and a custom field  description this is how i am able to fetch image and title

```
<?php
       $args=array('post_type' => 'partners');
       $query= new WP_Query($args);                               
       while ($query-> have_posts() ) : $query->the_post()?>
       <div class="col-lg-2 col-md-2 col-sm-4 col-xs-12">
       <?php the_title;?>
       <?php the_post_thumbnail( 'full', array( 'class' => 'innerimages') 
 );?>
        </div>
 <?php endwhile;?>
```

now how do i  print that custom field content after title ?please help

Answer (score 1):

Please, pay attention to the documentation of "Types" plugin:

...Types custom fields use the standard WordPress post-meta table, making it cross-compatible with any theme or plugin....

So, it is possible to get the values of custom fields using the  "get_post_meta" function:

`get_post_meta ( int $post_id, string $key = '', bool $single = false )`

If you know the name of custom field in the database, for example: description, it is possible to get its value into the loop, with the snippet of code:

`get_post_meta ( get_the_ID(), 'description' )`

Including the previous code in yours:

`<?php
    $args=array('post_type' => 'partners');
    $query= new WP_Query($args);

    while ($query-> have_posts() ) : $query->the_post()?>
    <div class="col-lg-2 col-md-2 col-sm-4 col-xs-12">
    <?php the_title;?>
    <?php the_post_thumbnail( 'full', array( 'class' => 'innerimages') );?>
    <?php print get_post_meta ( get_the_ID(), 'description' ); ?> 
    </div>
    <?php endwhile;?>`

and that's all.

Best regards.